# How to use webview in Android xml?

Tags: java, android

I have created layout.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mwebView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is in my Activity. I m getting this Web-view can not be resolved or is not a field and getting nullpointerexception.Here is my code.

```
     @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                mWebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mwebView);

                new getContactsTask().execute();

            }
```

Comment: please add logs from logcat

Comment: Is the layout you have created also named `layout.xml`? If yes, then the `setContentView` should be: `setContentView(R.layout.layout);`

Comment: No xml file name is main.

Comment: You really should check and recheck the name of the layout XML file. I don't see any other reason why this should occur.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Java code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout) //true
```

Instead of:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);  //false
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                   WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebView);
                   webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                   WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                   webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
                   String htmlCode="";
                   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlCode, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```